# How to adjust the volume level of the track when the automation points are already set?(Ableton/Logic pro)

Tags: logic-pro, ableton, volume, automation

when I do mixing in Ableton, I used to select all tracks and adjust the volume at once.
Whenever I do it, all the automations are off as the below screenshot.

In logic pro, I can't even adjust the track's volume when the automation is already set.

I try to achieve it by consolidating or bouncing the whole track. But I don't think it's a good option. Is there any other way to move all automation points at once?

[image: automation in ableton]

Comment: I'm interested in finding the solution to this as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To move the whole automation, you have to select the entire area of the automation first, then move it.

BUT..

This is a common problem, that pretty much everyone solves the same way.

Do not under any circumstances automate the final volume of a track...EVER.

In Ableton you drop a utility effect on the track and use it to do volume automation. This way you have automation independent of final volume.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to move all of it would be to select all of the nodes within the automation.  I don't know if there is a shortcut for that but if you hold shift and click and drag, you can select multiple nodes.  If you zoom all the way out, you can accomplish this much easier.

My preferred method for doing something like this, however, is to add an EQ or compressor (anything with an output gain though) and use that gain as a volume controller.  You could also do this in another order: automate your output gain on a plugin and you can still use the output volume on your track.

Another option would be to set up a bus for your output of the track you want to do this with, then apply your automation to the bus track and you can either use the volume on your actual track, or the send to the bus.

There's usually loads of ways to solve problems like this one, so it will really end up being about what you prefer to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Automate the level of a track use an automated  Utility on that / each track to get levels where you need them.
That way when you want to mix and Automate Track Volume you are not overriding your work.